# Java - How to fill a Windows L&F button with color instead of just the border?

Tags: java, swing, colors, jbutton, look-and-feel

I'm doing a few GUI tests with Java on Windows 7. I would like to use the Windows Look & Feel because Java's default "Metal" UI is really ugly IMO. When I set the background color of a button, it just colors the border around the button rather than fill its whole background.

```
public class GUITest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
        } catch(Exception e) {} // I know, not a good idea, but it's just a test

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        JButton button = new JButton("Windows L&F");
        button.setFocusable(false);
        button.setBackground(Color.GREEN.darker());

        frame.add(button);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

The result is this:

[image: (Windows Look & Feel)]

Whereas I'm aiming for something like this (but without using the Metal L&F):

[image: (Metal L&F)]

Is there a way to do that with the Windows L&F, or is it simply not built in?

Comment: Buttons on the Windows look and feel might not support this. Not really anything that you can do about it.

Answer (score 3):

Some PLAFs support (custom) colored buttons.  Others don't.

One way to achieve what you seem to want is to write the button text in an image with green BG and use the image for an icon of a button without text.

Answer (score 1):

If you want green filled in the button simply use 
`button.setBorderPainted(false);`

which will fill the whole button with your color as shown in your second picture.